# How to Convert below nested xml into array?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to convert this xml into array and then i have to pass that array as a parameter in _soapCall("OTA_HotelAvailRQ",array);
But i don't know how to convert this xml into array. Please help me.
 
       
        
         
        
       
       
        
         
         
          
           
            
           
          
         
         
          
           
           EUR
           
           EN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__soapCall()` is a low level function. You are not calling it directly, right? If you do call it directly keep in mind that:

- The arguments in the array must have
  the same order that the SOAP endpoint
  expects
- <strike>The array of arguments should be a
  flat one (no nested arrays)</strike>

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. can i use _call() instead of _soapCall()

Comment: Please show how do you create your SoapClient. Is it in non-WSDL mode? Usually you do not need to use `call()`. For example if your web service has a method with the following signature (using PHP syntax) `string function Hello(string $name)` then simply calling `$result = $soapClient->Hello('Joe')` would be enough. However your question is vague. What is the signature of the web service method you are trying to call? Is the service really SOAP-based or you have to send plain XML?